# Marlin 2.0 Change Bed Size at Runtime

Tags: 3d, printers

Is it possible to change the size of the bed at run-time? To clarify, I want to change the bed dimensions to effectively modify the probing-grid-area of the automatic-bed-leveling routine (I'll accept any answer that accomplishes this that **doesn't involve re-compiling Marlin firmware**).

**Details**

Printer: Flsun Q5 Auto Leveling Kossel Delta 3D Printer, but I've removed the hot-end and replaced it with a spring-loaded drawing tip with the Z-probe switch triggering when the spring is compressed sufficiently.

Controller: MKS-robin-nano

I need to draw on a rectangular work-piece that will inevitably have some slight curvature to it. Drawing on this surface requires relatively constant pressure. My hope is that I can do an automatic-bed-leveling (G29) on just the work-piece area, and then allow the leveling to produce a relatively constant drawing pressure along the surface.

Comment: This question probably belongs on this site: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one solution I found trying to do same thing as you. To clarify I am using marlin bugfix-2.0.x branch. If you choose `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR` in Configuration.h mariln uses the older (not unified) mesh bed leveling system. The example procedure for your case would then be:

1. Make sure you have flashed marlin with `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR`.
2. Move tool-head to the lower left corner (top view) of your rectangular work-piece just touching the surface either manually, using G-codes, repetier, pronterface, whatever.
3. `G92 X0 Y0 Z0` to set the machine position to 0,0,0.
4. `G29 F0 L0 R40 B20` to probe a 40mm by 20mm rectangle. The Mnemonic are: **F**ront, **L**eft, **R**ight, **B**ack.
5. `M500` to save the probed grid.
6. `M420 S1` to enable leveling to affect your G1-moves in probed area.
7. Execute your drawing G-code.

Be careful with `G29` command when using `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR` though, as some of the options described at [G29 marlin help page](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G029-abl.html) doesn't work e.g. I couldn't get the `P` option to work so to change probing grid size (amount of probe points) you have to recompile.
Also to then draw on the surface you may be using negative Z values for G1 moves in your G-code, in that case don't forget to `M211 S0` to be able to move below 0 (which would be your work-piece surface).

Comment: This is the level of quality all SO answers should have. Curious, do you happen to know if that “bug-fix” branch firmware version is required to achieve this result or can the vanilla one suffice? I’d like to stay on or near the master/trunk with this if possible.

Comment: This behaviour should be the same in branch 2.0.x, however I did not tested it.